# Why should I supply long options in addition to short options?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

A lot of shell scripts and commands support both short and long options, e.g.

```
$ ls -a
$ ls --all
```

But I just don't understand why. Why would one prefer the long to the short option, and why should I support both (when implementing my own scripts).

Comment: It's clearer to someone new to the code what you're doing if you use a longer option - probably not in this case I admit. Why would you use a short option? It's only 3 more characters.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it grew historically. Short options are easier to implement because you only have to check a single character, but are limited in terms of the number of possible options. Long options are more descriptive as well.

In terms of implementing both yourself, most libraries make it easy to implement both at the same time with essentially no additional code. I would tend to use long options because they are more descriptive, but that's purely a matter of preference.

Answer (score 3):

#### Why would someone prefer long-to-short?

Long options make it clearer what you are doing, and can give confidence to new users as well as making it easy for inexperienced users to understand what you are doing. For example, you would probably not run:

```
# DO NOT DO THIS PLEASE PLEASE
rm / --no-preserve-root --force --recursive
```

but you might run:

```
# DO NOT DO THIS PLEASE PLEASE
rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
```

if they don't understand exactly what it means.

It can also be used to make sure that the user ABSOLUTELY wants what they are doing, as in `--no-preserve-root` above, and to prevent mistyping a command with potentially disastrous results.

#### Why should I support both?

Well, because everyone does. It was sort of a historical thing, and by now many users have come to expect it. Libraries like `getopt` do it for you, so I don't see a good reason not to implant it.

#### Bonus: Why would someone prefer short-to-long?

Another question I frequently get it why would someone want short-to-long -- after all, aren't long options cleaner? Yes, but more experienced people will be angered by this. It is far faster to type `git commit -a -m 'message'` than `git commit --add --message 'message'`. Some libraries also allow you to chain short commands, so `command --long --another-long` can become `command -la`.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of options you need is more than the number of printable characters, then you need long options. It is about interaction with humans, there are pros and cons with either way.